# Get elements Id on expand event JQuery Mobile 1.4.3

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, expand, collapsable

I got 7 colabsibles. for each i'd like to loade a listview with Ajax on the expand event.

My html code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="workdaylists" data-inset="true" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="minus">
<div id="monday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headmonday">Montag</span></h3>
    <ul id="mondaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="tuesday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headtuesday">Dienstag</span></h3>
    <ul id="tuesdaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="wednesday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headwednesday">Mittwoch</span></h3>
    <ul id="wednesdaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="thursday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headthursday">Donnerstag</span></h3>
    <ul id="thursdaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="friday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headfriday">Freitag</span></h3>
    <ul id="fridaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="saturnday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headsaturnday">Samstag</span></h3>
    <ul id="saturndaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
<div id="sunday" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3><span id="headsunday">Sonntag</span></h3>
    <ul id="tuesdaylist" data-role="listview"></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#home', function(){
  $('#workdaylists').bind('collapsibleexpand', function () {
    alert("Expanded");
  });
})
```

How do I get the Id of the one thate expanded?

Thanks
Niki

Comment: `$(".ui-collapsible").on("collapsibleexpand", function () { alert(this.id); });`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this should work with jqm 1.4.2 version, didn't test for 1.4.3:

```
 $('#workdaylists').bind('collapsibleexpand', function (data) {

   console.log(data);
   console.log(data.target.id);
  });
```